# pass data to custom class in list

Tags: c#, list

here's my class

```
private class Events
    {
        public string eventID, eventName, eventTypeID, eventStartDate, eventEndDate;
    }
```

now on another method, I will get the list of eventID, eventName, etc2 and pass it to the Events class. So here's how I declare the Events instance:

```
List<Events> eventList = new List<Events>();
```

now how do I pass any data to eventList.eventID for example? I tried to get eventID data from database using the code below (but of course it is wrong)

```
while (reader.Read())
        {
            eventList.eventID.Add(reader["EventID"].ToString());
}
```

how do I achieve what I need? At the end of the day, I need a list of Events, where each contains the eventID, eventName and so on.

Comment: Do you mean `eventList.Add(new Event(reader["EventID"].ToString(), ...))` for each parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to loop over the reader and add a new object to the list for each model. like so:

```
while(reader.Read())
{ 
  event = new Events();
  event.eventID = reader["EventID"].ToString();
  ...
  eventList.add(event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a new `Events` object to the list, something like this:

```
eventList.Add(new Events() {
    eventID = reader["EventID"].ToString(),
    eventName = reader["EventName"].ToString(),
    ....
});
```